# developing several projects locally: How to configure environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, openshift

let's say I am developing 2 applications for 2 different clients which are, using 2 different database-configurations.

When using Openshift and CakePHP it is considered good practise to not store the real connection-info in the configs, but instead to use environment-variables.

That way the GIT-Repo is also always clean of server-specific stuff.

That is all fine as long as I have ONE project but as soon as there is another one, I need to override my local env-vars according to the current project.

Is there any way to avoid this? Is it possible to set up env-vars on my local machine per directory or something like that?

I am running OSX with Mamp Pro.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but It would work. Create a different user on your local machine and then change to that other user when you need to access those other environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I create a 'data' directory in my git repo and set it to ignore.  This way anything in there will be saved in the repo and sent to openshift.  I place a config.ini file with all the info that I don't want in my repo.

I then manually put that config.ini file in Openshift's persistent DATA directory by using winSCP.  You only have to do this when you change your config.ini.

When my app runs it detects if it's local or on Openshift and loads the config.ini file from the correct directory.

I would be interested if somebody has a better idea.

HTH